# Concatenating multiple text files by arguments in a script into a single file in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

How should i concatenate multiple text files get by arguments in terminal using a script in Bash?

```
#!/bin/bash
while read $1
do 
cat $1 > cat.txt
done
```

I tried that example but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should use '>>' to concatenate ('>' will create a new file each time):

```
for file in "$@"
do
    cat $file >> result
done
```

Comment: Actually the proper way to do that is `for file in "$@"; do cat "$file"; done >result` with the redirection after the `done` and with proper quoting of `"$file"``